# how to get a jquery variable value

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery variable

```
$('#myValue')
```

In firebug if I hover over the variable at runtime I can see the the variable value "help". How can I get the the value "help" from the jquery variable and assign it to a javascript variable;

I have tried:

```
 var text = $('#myValue')
```

this jut creates an empty object

I have also tried

```
  var text = $('#myValue').text()
```

Which returns an empty String "".

And I have tried

```
var text = $('#myValue').val()
```

Which returns undefined.

Comment: I think you need `$('#myValue').text()`

Comment: What you show should work fine - what do you mean by "value" exactly though?

Comment: It's unclear what you want... What kind of element do you expect to find with your selector?  What data are you looking to get out of it?  My guess would be `$('#myValue')` is supposed to find a div or something, but you never say...

Comment: `$('#myValue')` isn't a variable, it's a jQuery method call which looks for an element in your page with the ID 'myValue'. It may be useful to show your HTML fragment here, and explain what property you are trying to manipulate in your code

Comment: Incomplete question, don't run away so fast! :-) Like.. what is the "variable" ?

Comment: I've edited the post, I hope that is clearer.

Comment: @user86834 It isn't...There is no such thing as a jQuery variable, jQuery is simply a collection of JavaScript functionality; it's the same language.

Comment: It seems you are somewhat confused about JavaScript terminology.  It is very important to use the correct terms when communicating with others.  For example, `$('#foo')` is not a variable.  It is a function call that searches for an element.

Comment: You say you see the word `"help"`, but we have no way of knowing what that means.  Is that the text inside a div?  The value of a select option?  We can't tell you how to get the data if we have no idea what it is.  You should create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).  If you don't want to do that, you should at least include some HTML to give us an idea of what's happening.  We can't read your mind!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this question has been clowning around for long enough. For the benefits of that question, I will clarify something: `$('#myValue')` is a jQuery selector that points toward **an element with ID "myValue"**, just as it is used in css :

```
#myValue { display:block;width:100px;height:100px; }
```

This line will instruct the page that the element with ID "myValue" needs to be displayed as a 100x100 block.

Then,

```
var text = $('#myValue');
```

will hold the element with ID "myValue", if it ever exists. **(IT WON'T GET THE VALUE OF ANY VARIABLE CALLED myValue)**

To make sure that the element exists, you may test it like this:

```
if ($('#myValue').length > 0) {
    // the element exists
}
```

There is no wizardry around jQuery selectors, you can take a look yourself at [this reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). To get the text / value of an element you have many options depending on what the element is and what you want to access within it.

- Text inside a tag like div, span, etc. : `$('#elementID').text();`
- Value of an option, input, button, etc. : `$('#elementID').val();`
- All the html content within a tag : `$('#elementID').html();`
- Etc.

If, however, you really want to get the value of a variable, I would ask you this: why do you need to put its value into another variable ?

I hope this will clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery makes it easy to select HTML elements and manipulate them from your JavaScript code. The jQuery function `$` can take a selector string as a parameter to select an element by ID.

For example, to select the HTML div element

```
<div id="myValue">Some Text</div>
```

one would invoke `$("#myValue")`, which returns a jQuery object. This jQuery object contains, among other things, a collection of matched elements. Since we identified this element specifically by its ID, the collection should contain only this single element.

In practice, this can be used in any number of ways. To get the text content, you can invoke `.text()` on the jQuery object. To set an attribute, you can invoke `.attr(name, value)`, and so on. The full method list is in [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

For a simple test example, try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script for jquery source>
<script> YOUR_CODE_HERE </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myValue">Some Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the script tag, the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // get text
    var text = $("#myValue").text();
    alert(text);

    // make it blue
    $("#myValue").css("background-color", "LightBlue");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CBZq7/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am not pulling the value from HTML.

Comment: @user86834 `$("#myValue")` attempts to read from the DOM. It is looking for an HTML element, and if it doesn't find one it won't have any properties for you to get. Posting an example of your code would be helpful here.

Comment: I think my situation is a bit different, i assign a value to to my varaible, i.e. var myValue = "help", I go to a different page, If I use the browser back button I can see the value "help" if I hover over $("#myValue") in firebug. Does this make sense?

Comment: It is as if JQuery has cached the the variable.

Comment: @user86834 No, it hasn't done that. I don't know what you are seeing in firebug, but `var myValue = "help"` has nothing to do with jQuery. That is a plain JavaScript variable declaration, and it will go away once you navigate away. The jQuery syntax `$("#myValue")` does not refer to variables at all---it is, by definition, looking for an HTML element with the ID "myValue". If it is set then that element is on your page somewhere.

Comment: @user86834 - This question gets more and more confusing as you provide more and more nebulous details... **PLEASE** provide some example HTML or at least describe something clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

1.) `var text = $('#myValue').val();`

OR

2.) you get from variable like this:

```
var text = $('#myValue');

text.val();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var jqval = $('#myValue').val();
```

Comment: This results in undefined.

Comment: @user86834 [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) is for use with input elements. We have no idea what kind of element you're referring to, or what you are trying to access on it.

Comment: if the element type is input then use : .val() otherwise use .text()
or you also use .attr() to get different attribute of the tag.

Comment: If you read the comments under other answers, it appears that the OP is quite confused about what `$('#myValue')` actually means...